# Where's this pond and waterfall in Yosemite National Park?

Tags: identify-this, yosemite

I stumbled this at [r/earthporn](https://redd.it/8o8b13).

[image]

Comment: More of a small lake than a pond, I'd say.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP does not appear to have attempted any prior research, nor have they explained the reason for the question.

Comment: @Traveller You appear ignored my comment above. I wrote "I'm planning a big road trip in US after COVID19! We want hit all these beauties!" I searched this pic on Google but got nothing.

Comment: @PL You post photos taken from spring to autumn, and spanning New England to Alaska, and you claim to be 'planning a road trip'. I find that really difficult to believe.

Comment: It took me less than 30 seconds to identify this waterfall. I don't believe this is a genuine question. Voting to close.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Sorry, but your comments feel negative and not nice like "I don't believe this is a genuine question". I put this picture in Google reverse search and got nothing. Why not show how you identify this waterfall less than 30 seconds? And I can't take more one trip? Or is your issue me personally?

Comment: @PL: please please answer in the meta question about the sockpuppets!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The falls are Yosemite Falls, by far the most popular falls in the park.

The "pond" isn't a pond at all, but instead a flooded meadow along the banks of the Merced river that runs through Yosemite Valley.  During period of either heavy rain and/or heavy snow-melt it's not uncommon for the meadows along along the Merced to flood which is clearly what's happened here as there are no "ponds" or lakes of that size anywhere near the point where this photo was taken.

Based on the aspect of the falls, I'd say that this photo was taken somewhere around the "Swinging Bridge" (which, oddly enough, doesn't swing).  If I had to guess I'd say this photo was probably taken in either April or May, but it could be a month either side depending on the weather at the time.